# What is the data option of eth_sendTransaction?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

I am trying to send ERC20 token using JSON RPC. I am very new in this step and learning. I am using eth_sendTransaction function. What is "value" and "data" option in this case ? Please help

Answer (score 0):

`value` is the amount of ethereum you want to send (in wei). `data` is the message that you want to send. When you send your transaction to a smart contract, that message contains its parameters.

Comment: Suppose I want to send 20 token (ERC 20). what will be the value ? is that 20 ? and what should be the data plz explain..

Comment: No, ERC20 doesn't work that way. When you send ERC20 tokens you have to send a transaction to the contract of that ERC20 token, eg. `0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52` if you want to send BNB. In particular, you call the `transfer(to, amount)` function of that contract. With web3 you probably should use a default ERC20 ABI.

Comment: where to define the contract in JSON RPC. there is no option found

Comment: What do you mean by "define"?

Comment: Ok, maybe I can guess what you mean. You send the transaction *to* the contract, so the contract is the receiver of that transaction. The receiver of the ERC20 tokens is then encoded in the data field (together with the amount of tokens and the function id of `transfer(to, amount)`).

Comment: exactly that I want. Buy how to do that ? using eth_sendTransaction method ? if yes then what should I put in "data" option ?

Comment: If you really have to use the raw RPC method, `data` should look like this: `0xA9059CBB000000000000000000000000FDD7B006F6E4209DD970FFA12EE77C37CBDCEA42000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000A2A5CDE79F940000`. The first part is the function id of `transfer(to,amount)`, `FD...42` is the receiver of the tokens and the last part is the amount of tokens (in its smallest unit, encoded as big endian). Something like web3 would make this much more simple though ;)

Comment: ok. now how the function will know that which contract I am calling ? where to specify it ?

Comment: As I said, you send that transaction **to** the contract, so you put the contract address as the receiver of the transaction (the `"to"` field of eth_sendTransaction).

Comment: ok all things done. but it is ending ether insted of token.. what to do here !

Comment: umm... what ending?